# Window close event on user logoff/machine shutdown

Tags: wpf, events, formclosing

I have a WPF application with one window.  The user cannot terminate this application but can close the window.

I have the following code that prevents the window from closing

```
        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

All works fine.

However when the application shuts down by user logoff or machine shutdown I need to save a collection of data to an XML file.  I am fine doing the save but cannot figure out what event to use.  From what I have read when the `Application.SessionEnding` event is fired the window may not be accessible?  All the posts I have read talk about Application shutdown events but none have given me a clue about being able to access data in a window before it closing.

Is there a way of determining how the window is being closed in the above event?

Comment: You could simply check if window is already hidden, if so, you need to do the thing and close window for real.

Comment: Not sure how that would help me but thanks. I do not want the user to be able to terminate the program at all unless they logoff or shutdown.  When the user logs off or shuts the machine down the window may not be hidden.

Comment: Then how about using SystemEvents.SessionEnded?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx